# Organizer reporting, "The version of iPhone OS doesn't match iPhone OS supported for development"

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, xcode3.2, organizer

Earlier this week I was developing to the device just fine. I upgraded itunes to the latest version (9.0.2 (25)) and I noticed that Organizer was throwing the:

> The version of iPhone OS on “sk’s
>   iPhone” does not match any of the
>   versions of iPhone OS supported for
>   development

So I figured I'd upgrade to the newest XCode in hopes that it would solve the problem. Well, it didn't - After an upgrade to Xcode 3.2.2 Organizer is still throwing the error and not letting me build to the device.

Image of the exact error message: http://mr-sk.com/iphone/organizer.png

Edit: I installed the 3.2 SDK - Apparently I missed out on the 3.1.3 SDK - any idea how to fix this?

Side note: This ALWAYS seems to happen to me - every time I upgrade. Last time I believed it was fixed by some random terminal command (sym linking a path? - I can't recall) but it's a PITA that this never, ever, seems to work smoothly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You installed 3.1.3 on your phone, but did not get the updated 3.1.3 SDK.

Install the latest 3.1.3 SDK recently released from Apple.  Then, to develop for iPad, install the 3.2 SDK Beta to a different location in the installer.  This will allow you to use the official version now, and still play with the beta version with the iPad simulator.

Comment: 3.1.3 SDK came out after the 3.2 SDK did.  The 3.2 SDK beta 1 does not include support for 3.1.3 devices.  My point is that you should not use the BETA SDK for current iPhone development because of issues like these.  That said I think 3.2 beta 2 does have 3.1.3 OS support now.  But it's still a bad idea to use it for 3.1.3 development.

Comment: Right, I get that. BUT, I've already installed it...so how can I fix this issue?

Comment: install the 3.1.3 SDK again. It will overwrite whatever it needs to

Comment: (+1) Ah ok - easy enough. Then reinstall the 3.2 but to another directory.

Comment: Great, that worked. Now, I just need to install 3.2 to a different dir.